# AccountID is not returned in response message from DocuSign for CreateAndSendEnvelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign API's CreateAndSendEnvelope method to create the envelope.
I am able to create the envelope successfully but in the response message received from DocuSign I am not getting "AccountID".

However, I am getting AccountID from DocuSign if I check the connect messages (Preferences -> Connect -> Logs) as CustomField.

Please help me how I can get the AccountId in case of CreateAndSendEnvelope.

Comment: Have read any of the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) or looked at any of the SOAP WSDLs?  AccountId is not returned from the CreateAndSendEnvelope call, you need to make the Login API call instead.

Answer (score 0):

The AccountId is not returned from the CreateEnvelopeXXX() calls, you need to make the Login API call to retrieve your AccountId.  The Login call is part of the Credential API, as explained in the SOAP API docs:

[SOAP PDF Guide (page223)](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf#page=223)

The Login Result returns `AccountId`, `AccountName`, `UserId`, `UserName`, `Email`, and `BaseUrl`.